# returning a draggable li to its original index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have several dynamically generated unordered lists.  The `<li>`'s within them are draggable/droppable elements which are apended into a div when dropped there.

I want to be able to return these `<li>`'s into their original lists and at the same index so that they are in exactly the same position as before.

I have been able to achieve this by doing the following:-

When dragging the element using the .data function as below:

```
$item.data('originalParent', $(this).prev());
```

Then when I return the element using this:-

```
.insertAfter( $item.data('originalParent') )
```

This of course works great, however a problem arises when I have also dragged the previous `<li>` into the droppable box since the item is appended next to that, instead of in the original parent at the correct index.

How else can I dynamically store the index location so that I can return it to the correct parent `<ul>` at the correct `<li>` index?  Even if the number of `<li>` elements has changed in the `<ul>`.

I hope this is clear enough as I am finding it difficult to articulate.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to satisfy both conditions: 1: Remember the previous index of the `<li>` **and** 2. Allow the number of `<li>` elements to change.

Comment: Can't you just label your lists and items before page load storing the original position, when you need to return an element back refer to that data? <ul list="1"><li list="1" item="1"></li><li list="1" item="2"></li></ul>  <ul list="2"><li list="2" item="1"></li><li list="2" item="2"></li></ul>

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes I understand that... What I am looking for is some sort of workaround so that I can return it to its previous element exists in the original parent.  But if not append it to the closest possible index.  i.e. if I am returning <li> index 5 but <li> index 4 no longer exists, append it to <li> index 4 instead... Or something similar.  It's a tricky one I know...

Comment: Thanks Jeff,  I have toyed with exactly this idea.  However this alone will not return the item to the correct location as I would still need a reference list item to insert to.  If the reference list item is also moved into the droppable box, so will the list items I am trying to return.  i.e. if both <li list="1" item="1"> and <li list="1" item="2"> are dragged and dropped into the target box.  If I try to return <li list="1" item="2"> by means of .insertafter on <li list="1" item="1"> it won't return to the correct place.

Comment: Jeff - I feel that the answer lies somewhere in your suggestion, but there is still a piece of the puzzle I am missing.

Comment: Could you possibly post the HTML and JS code into http://jsfiddle.net so we could see the behaviour?

Comment: When the li is dropped you can store the list and item data along with it, when you want to return it back to the list it came from you can use those and reference the lists through $('ul[list=' + <stored list num> + ']') and use that to find the li in that list by minusing 1 from the stored item num so if the num was 2 you'd find li with the item of 1 using $('li[item=1]') and insert the li after it back into its original position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gordyr to expand on my comments since its easier to type and show examples here if you have a setup like

```
<ul list="1">
    <li list="1" item="1"></li>
    <li list="1" item="2"></li>
</ul>
<ul list="2">
    <li list="2" item="1"></li>
    <li list="2" item="2"></li>
</ul>
```

When a list item is dropped you can grab and store its `list` and `item` attributes using

```
list =  $(this).attr('list');
item =  $(this).attr('item');
// store this list and item variable data with the div or parent of where ever the list item was dropped
```

when you want to reset the dragged list item back to its original spot in the UL it came from, read the list and item variable you stored with it, we'll say you grabbed them and they are stored in `list` and `item` and the li to restore is `element`

To restore the list item to its original position you can do something like:

```
if (item == 1)
{
    // the list item being restored is the first so prepend it to the beginning of the list it came from
    element.prependTo( $('ul[list=' + list + ']') );
}
else
{
    // the list item is not the first so find the item before it in the list it came from and insert it after that list item
    element.insertAfter( $('ul[list=' + list + '] li[item=' + (item - 1) + ']') );
}
```

Hope this helps any, I could be just way off on what your trying to do.  The examples above still would need to be expanded upon, like the last one, since it's just going back one item in the list, that item could of been moved also so it wont be in the list so you'd have to keep iterating back till you found the next item in the list and insert it after that one.

If the item is 4, look for item 3 in the list, if not there then 2, if not there then 1, if 1 isn't there then prepend to the beginning of the list.

Comment: It's the right idea, but the implementation will be a more involved than this suggests. Additionally, creating your own attributes on-the-fly like that (without defining your own DocType) could have unpredictable side-effects. It might be wiser to record the data in JS list at runtime if you don't want to use a cipher of ids or classes.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you actually want the li's sorted in a specific way as far as I can tell.

You could just sort them just after you add a li to it, or remember the order (using something like .data('index') to set/retrieve the index) and put the li to the appropriate place.

The last part can be done by iterating over the parents' children, and put it before the first that has a higher index, or at the end.

Comment: I've been able to achieve roughly want i want by using a string of if else statements combined with catching the index with .data.  It feels very 'hacky' and I don't like it at all but it is working.  I'll play around and post up a more elegant answer for nyone else looking for something similar if I find a better solution.  Cheers!

Comment: Although your answer got me there Johan, i'm afraid Jeff's was more complete (albeit using data storage within the DOM which I prefer to stay away from).  Therefore I am giving him the 'answer'.  Huge thanks for the help though.